# Media Server on the Pi with Lan connection to TV

Tags: wifi, streaming, media-server

Is there a way to set up a media server on the Pi for streaming Video Files, and have a TV connect to it over Lan?

The TV could, in theory, access a media server that is running on the router, I am, however, experiencing quite some difficulty with connecting the TV over Wlan to the Media server on the router, therefore a Lan connection would probably be a better solution.

(Both devices are in different rooms, a Lan connection to the router is sadly not possible)

Comment: If the TV has a wired network port, is it also a smart TV? Does it have a dlna player app? My Samsung TV does, and I use a Pi as a dlna server. The server software on the Pi can be minidlna or Serviio that I know of, there are probably others

Comment: Yes, the TV has a Lan port, the problem is its WiFi Reception, so I could run  minidlna or Serviio on the Pi, and connect the TV with Lan to the Pi?

Comment: You need to connect the TV to the router. See my answer below.

Comment: See update about wifi extenders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 2012 Samsung smart TV which has a dlna client. Like you, I cannot link my TV directly to the router using Ethernet cable. My Raspberry Pi 4 replaces (and works better than) a 2012 Seagate Goflex NAS (it died) which also had minidlna running. To connect the TV to the router I used what are called powerline adapters. They plug into AC outlets and use your house wiring. One near the TV and one near the router. The ones I use I bought in 2012 and are 300 Mbit rated and I can stream 1080p 50Hz with no problems or freezes. Mine are TP-Link like the picture but there are plenty of other brands. They cost from $50 per pair upwards. You pay more for higher speeds. Search for 'powerline adapter'.

[image]

Another solution might be to use 'wifi extenders' which work the same way. This would extend the wifi coverage for all devices in the area near the remote adapter.

[image]